# Getting only 1 decimal place

Tags: python, rounding

How do I convert `45.34531` to `45.3`?

Answer (score 246, accepted):

Are you trying to represent it with only one digit:

```
print("{:.1f}".format(number)) # Python3
print "%.1f" % number          # Python2
```

or actually round off the other decimal places?

```
round(number,1)
```

or even round strictly down?

```
math.floor(number*10)/10
```

Comment: Is there any chance that your 1st and 3rd solution gives different results? I think they both are exactly same @relet

Comment: Try number=-2.55. They also return different types.

Comment: @DeveshSaini try number 2.36. 1st will give 2.4, 3nd will give 2.3

Answer (score 42):

```
>>> "{:.1f}".format(45.34531)
'45.3'
```

Or use the builtin round:

```
>>> round(45.34531, 1)
45.299999999999997
```

Comment: Update: Round gives me 45.3 nowdays.

Comment: This is answer is correct but the formatting is way to complicated IMO. You should just write `"{:.1f}".format(45.34531)`.

Comment: @DaveHalter, writing out `0.1` instead of `.1` is way to complicated, how can anyone even follow that code...

Comment: There's also a zero in front that is not necessary. I also think that nobody really understands the format language so keeping it simple is preferred IMO.
Now with Python 3.6 I would recommend writing it like this: `f"{number:.1f}"`.

Answer (score 21):

```
round(number, 1)
```