# Repeating a block of "If" statement

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a text based game, and to make my fighting mechanics I have to repeat an if statement until you or the monster dies.

Here it is --
`Ph` would stand for Player health, `str` is player strength, `mdam` is monster damage, `mstr` is monster strength, `monsterh` is monsterhealth, the `random.random()` is the attack bonus you receive (Adding onto this, is there any way to round the number to one or no decimal places?) Thank you! :D

```
if fight == "A" and ph > 0:
    damage = (str) + (random.random())
    monsterh = 6
    mstr = 0.9
    monsterh = (monsterh) - (damage)
    print(damage)
    print(damage - str)
    print('You attack the monster. You deal %s damage.' % damage ) 
    time.sleep(3)
    if monsterh > 0:
        mstr = 0.9
        mdam = (mstr) + (random.random())
        print('The monster attacks you!')
        ph = ph - mstr
        print("You get hit %s" % mdam )
    else:
        xpgain = damage + 5
        print("You won! You've gained %s XP!" % xpgain)
```

Comment: You want a `while` loop.  Check out https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=flow%20control.

Comment: You could put the whole thing in a loop:  `while i_am_not_dead and monster_is_not_dead: ...`

Answer (score 0):

To round the value you get from

```
random.random()
```

you can do

```
round(random.random(),1)
```

to round to 1 decimal place, or if you want to get rid of decimals, replace

```
random.random()
```

with

```
int(random.random())
```

As for repeating the if statement, you can put it into a loop which will break when a condition is met

```
while true:
    if fight == "A" and ph > 0:
        damage = (str) + (int(random.random()))
        monsterh = 6
        mstr = 0.9
        monsterh = (monsterh) - (damage)
        print(damage)
        print(damage - str)
        print('You attack the monster. You deal %s damage.' % damage ) 
        time.sleep(3)
    elif ph<=0 or fight!="A":
        print("You lose!")
        break
    if monsterh > 0:
        mstr = 0.9
        mdam = (mstr) + (int(random.random()))
        print('The monster attacks you!')
        ph = ph - mstr
        print("You get hit %s" % mdam )
    else:
        xpgain = damage + 5
        print("You won! You've gained %s XP!" % xpgain)
        break
```

Although you wouldn't need the

```
fight!="A"
```

since I don't think you change the value of fight at all.

Also you don't have to do

```
mdam = (mstr) + (int(random.random()))
```

You can just do

```
mdam = mstr+int(random.random())
```

This above ^ applies to other places in your code as well. If you have any questions please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap your combat seen in a while loop. For example:

```
while (ph > 0 or monsterh > 0)
    # combat rules

# Check who died and move on from there
if (ph > 0)
    # next thing the player does
else
    # print "You died"
```

In regards to rounding, there are multiple options depending on exactly what you want to do: [python: getting only 1 decimal place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400965/python-getting-only-1-decimal-place)