# Retaining first number after the decimal in python

Tags: python, excel-formula

I want python to do something similar to MS Excel `=ROUNDDOWN (number, num_digits)` . So in my example which looks like this

```
a = [3.5, 43.689, 113.225, 65.4545]
```

I tried like this:

```
a = [3.5, 43.689, 113.225, 65.4545]
b = [str(i).split(".") for i in a]

c = [i[0] for i in b]
d = [i[1][0] for i in b]

e = list(zip(c,d))
f = [float(".".join(i)) for i in e]
```

which gave an OUTPUT i need:

```
>>> print (f)
[3.5, 43.6, 113.2, 65.4]
```

Is there a better and simplest way to do the above in Python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400965/python-getting-only-1-decimal-place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` rounds towards zero if that is what you want:

```
a = [3.5, 43.689, 113.225, 65.4545]
[int(x * 10) / 10 for x in a]
```

Output:

```
[3.5, 43.6, 113.2, 65.4]
```

Answer (score 3):

Same way as you almost:

```
a = [3.5, 43.689, 113.225, 65.4545]
f = [float("{:.1f}".format(x)) for x in a]
```

Anyhow, have in mind that you can just work with the decimals and use the format for its representation.

You can transform then with math `floor` like this:

```
import math
f = [math.floor(x * 10)/10.0 for x in a]
print(f)
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/KahN/1).

Comment: `ROUNDDOWN` always rounds towards zero.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, true, just realize it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's more Pythonic way:

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_DOWN
Decimal(65.4545).quantize(Decimal('.0'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use round expression:

```
>>> a = [3.5, 43.689, 113.225, 65.4545]
>>> [float(Decimal(b).quantize(decimal.Decimal('.0'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_DOWN)) for b in a]
[3.5, 43.6, 113.2, 65.4]
```

I hope this help you ;)

Comment: Does not yield he expected result. 43.7 != 43.6